# google maps api multiple scripts use sensor or not

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a site that has two maps on one page one uses the sensor and one doesn't. If I add two scripts I get errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true"></script>
```

Am I just supposed to use one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you only use one.

If you want to use the sensor then set it to true. Likewise if you don't want to use it.

In my experience leaving it as true causes no issues if you don't plan to use it.